# how can I avoid getting 0 as a print value for adding pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, addition

while I was trying to understand how pointers work in C I wrote the following code that takes input and adds it to one, then it prints it out, but the problem is I keep getting a zero/null every time it prints the output, how can I avoid it printing a null value?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int **q_Quantity,*pQuantity,input =0;

    printf("Enter number:");
    scanf("%d",&*pQuantity); //takes input
    
    //pQuantity = (int *)malloc(*pQuantity+sizeof(int)*1);

    pQuantity = *&pQuantity+1;//gives a 0

    printf("%d\n",*pQuantity);
}
```

Comment: What you're doing is undefined behavior, you're lucky to be getting any output at all.

Comment: What do you suppose the difference is between `&*pQuantity` and `pQuantity`?

Comment: Was I supposed to store it in an int variable , like `int sum = *&pQuantity+1;` ? 
is it not possible to add the 1 to the pointer and then print it?

Comment: ohh, I realized my mistake thank you Ninja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pQuantity` is *uninitialized* when you pass it to `scanf`, so its value is **indeterminate**.  `scanf` then attempts to dereference that uninitialized pointer to write the value read from the user.  Attempting to read and dereference an indeterminate pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, when you apply the `&` operator to the result of the `*` operator they cancel each other out.  So `&*pQuantity` is exactly the same as `pQuantity`.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
int *pQuantity,input =0;
pQuantity = &input;

printf("Enter number:");
scanf("%d",pQuantity);

*pQuantity = *pQuantity+1;
printf("%d\n",*pQuantity);
```

Comment: oh, I see, so I should always assign pointers to something. thank you so much